# Does hook menu accept a wildcard as argument 0?

Tags: 7

In a custom module I have implemented `hook_menu()` using the following code.

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = [];

  $items['%/review'] = [
    'page callback' => 'review',
    'page arguments' => [0],
    'access arguments' => ['access content'],
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

Wildcard should be existing node. I am trying to access mydomain.com/product1/reviews (where product1 is node/1) and then print some related product data on reviews page.

I'm getting a 404 error. If I change `$items['%/review']` to  `$items['abc/%']` everything works. What can be the problem?

Note: I don't want to change node route. I want to access this path mydomain.com/product1/reviews where product1 is an existing node.

Comment: You can't have a wildcard as the first argument.

Comment: @Kevin how should I target for example path mydomain.com/product1/reviews (product1 being node/1)  ? Thank you

Comment: Why change the node route?

Comment: @Kevin I don't want to change node route. I want to access this path mydomain.com/product1/reviews where product1 is existing node.

Comment: You want a path alias for that.

Comment: @Jaypan Not sure if I understand. How can I make path alias for mydomain.com/product1/reviews where product1 is a node (should be product2,3 etc) and  url mydomain.com/product1/reviews should show some data related to product

Comment: Enable the Path module (part of core). Edit the node. Set the path in the 'URL Alias' section.

Comment: @Jaypan I appreciate your help but it seems you did not get the question fully. I edited the question.

Comment: You still cannot have a wildcard as the first argument. It would have to be node/%node/reviews or product/%node/reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your products are nodes, this is what you need to do

```
  $items['node/%node/review'] = [
    'page callback' => 'my_module_review',
    'page arguments' => [1],
    'access arguments' => ['access content'],
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  ];
```

In your callback

```
function my_module_review($node) {
  // since you used %node you have access directly to the $node object here as param
}
```

So basically right now you can only access it via `/node/{nid}/review` similarly how you can access the edit form via `/node/{nid}/edit`

Now, install & enable **[Sub-pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto)**

> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites
>   the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased
>   URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking
>   a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview)

So it converts it to `/{node-alias}/review` and also you'll now be able to access the node edit form via `/{node-alias}/edit`

Comment: I think I found simpler solution. Please look at last comment https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-11-08/trying-to-get-current-page-url-for#comment-5222266

Comment: That forum post is for Drupal 6.

Comment: And it seems that also putting %wildcard to the first place on menu path and calling %wildcard_to_arg() does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards may not be used as the first component of a route path in `hook_menu`. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

what can you do if you want this feature, the solution is kind of tricky solution like

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = [];
 $myItems =  // load what do you have
foreach($myItems as $myItem){
  $items[$myItem.'/review'] = [
    'page callback' => 'review',
    'page arguments' => [0],
    'access arguments' => ['access content'],
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  ];
}

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Interesting creative solution, but if you have lots of `$myItems`, when there is no cache yet (cache is invalidated/flushed for whatever reason), the site will load slow until all those menu items get cached. Also, the cache table for these menus items will be larger.

Comment: @NoSssweat, yes, it has this limitation, but when he/she want this it seems there is no more option. as I deduced from the question number of the items are not alot.

Comment: See my answer for the better way.

Comment: @NoSssweat `node/%node/review`, this is another tricky solution and particularly for node and other entities and it never works for custom routes. btw, it's working for his/her case ;-). thank you.